# OOP C++ help needed

Tags: c++, oop, stl, logic

This will look a bit strange, I know. It's not a common request. I have failed my first exam at OOP programming (in C++) and I have 4-5 days to prepare for the second and last time I can take this exam. I know the theory quite well, I'm not that good though at programming using many things like: virtual/static functions, static/dynamic/.. cast, STL lists, overloading operators, conversion constructors and some other things. I have read the theory, I just don't know where and how to apply it.

What I ask (better to say beg) you to do for me is nothing more than giving me some exercises or an idea of a program/project that will include most of these things. I don't need the code (how to solve them), although some hints would be nice.

I'm hoping at least some of you will understand my situation and won't ignore my request.

Thank you in advance,
Matt

Comment: +1 for openly admitting that you have failed the exam. Needs courage to accept it among public.

Comment: You have only 4 days. And you must learn C++. I would recommend you to get questions from exam(ask your classmates and collect them). You also might try to pass some online C++ tests.

Comment: @iammilind Internet != public; Internet = anonymous;

Comment: failed.. not by far.. 2 points separated me from passing the exam..

Comment: @Matt get CodeBlocks and do some examples. A nice start project might be to implement a file parser, but with a user defined filter read from an xml file. Something like that.

Comment: @Matt.. As you said you just left with only 4 days, better you pick few topics with which you are already bit familiar and try to get good command over them instead going through all. And anyway you are confidant with  Theory part its never be problem to pass the exam if you can present it properly. But do not Expect a Magic from others.

Answer (score 0):

[Schaum's Outline of Programming with C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071353461) and [Teach Yourself C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0078823927) contain nice exercise at end of each chapters (probably with solution too). They are good for beginners. As you know the theories, you can directly jump to the exercise.

Comment: @Dennis, @Kirill, thanks for the suggestions. Somehow searching online for tests didn't cross my mind, guess I was too affected by the failure. thanks once again!

Comment: thank you. I've read Teach Yourself C++, the exercises tend to be a bit difficult for me from time to time. But I'll certainly take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/quiz/). There are a series of C++ quizzes of varying difficulty. I'm not sure what level you're looking for, but I hope this helps.

EDIT: Upon actually looking at the quizzes, it looks like there's no coverage of OOP there. Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks anyway. I know about the site, have been there quite a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

First of all, you are very close to the pass of the exam. Be confident and get prepared!

If I were you, I will do like this.

1. Select top important concepts that I don't know how to use/apply. Write down questions/problems that made you fail(if you know that). Let's say, if you have four days before next exam, look into 5 concepts a day, you'll learn a lot(20 concepts). I'm sure that'll help you earn that 2 scores:)
2. For each concept, I'll search it in MSDN. The advantage of it is in addition to well-explained text, there are lots of examples involved for each concept, most importantly for you, most examples are small and independent. **I recommend you setup an environment(MSVC or whatever) and examine those examples by yourself**.

Comment: thank you! 20 concepts seems a lot to digest, but I will certainly give it a try. you know what they say, sky is the limit :)

Comment: I have been using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for a while now :) nothing new to get acquired with.

Comment: the thing is, my teacher usually gives the source code of a program, and either something is wrong with it and we have to tell what or it's all very narrow and fuzzy and we have to tell the output of the program. i think the only way i can manage this task is by exercising a lot.. that's why i was asking for exercises.

Comment: @Matt, that's good! To feed your need, I guess one place to look for is C++ interview question. Some of them give you a piece of code and let you detect the error or the program output. Just for your reference.

Comment: If you do use MSVC make sure (maybe after the exam) that you really learned C++, and not some MS dialect of it. Microsoft is a bit lax in differentiating those, especially on MSDN (also of late they got much better than a few years ago).